# Gradle JVM version doesn't match the used JDK version

Tags: java, linux, gradle

In the screenshot below, you can see what I am using the `11.0.11` JDK version but my Gradle uses the `1.8.0_282` JVM version. And it's not a problem because for set the Java version in a project using [Gradle Toolchain](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html).

[image]

I'm not sure but it looks strange. Is it worth worrying about and can I specify a specific JVM version (11)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a java executable on your `PATH` that doesn't match up with a configured `JAVA_HOME` environment. Gradle uses the `JAVA_HOME` to detect the java installation to use.

Comment: I think this is correct. If you are on ubuntu, I recommend using update-alternatives to manage your java version, it should handle this for you

Comment: Hello @wakingrufus.
I use fedora I search how to set `JAVA_HOME` using `alternatives`.

Comment: Hmm .. I've set my `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java` but Gradle still uses `1.8` probably maybe I was wrong in the settings. Anyway, let's mark it as the answer.  Thanks @Rene Groeschke and @wakingrufus !

Comment: `update-alternatives` should not change `JAVA_HOME` except if you point `JAVA_HOME` to a symlink directory that points to the actual Java to use. Gradle wrapper script and also Gradle start script will prefer `JAVA_HOME` if it is set and if not use the `java` found on the `PATH`. So if you do `echo $JAVA_HOME` you should see the Java that is used by Gradle. If you set `JAVA_HOME` to a different Java that will be used and if you unset it, then the `java` from the `PATH` will be used..

Comment: Hello @Vampire ! I've understood my mistake and set `JAVA_HOME` correctly. The result of the `echo $JAVA_HOME` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java` but the `gradle -v` is showing `JVM 1.8.0_282`.
Now, I try to set `JAVA_HOME` as more specific.

Comment: And `/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java -version` is showing Java 11?

Comment: Hello @Vampire. Yes, it's. The result `/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java -version` is `openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20`.

Comment: That's really strange then. I'm really curious whether you find out what is happening. I guess a next step would be to change the content of `gradle` to have as first statement `set -x` too see what is going on within the script.